# Oracle apex 5 language change

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

java script function not work in Oracle apex 5

```
javascript:doSubmit('en');
```

> error Uncaught Reference Error: do Submit is not defined(…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
javascript:apex.submit('en');
```